# Cannot subscript a value

Tags: alamofire, swift2, xcode7-beta2

I created a brand new Swift project, then added the following `podfile` to it

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'LifeStream' do
pod 'SSKeychain'
pod 'LiveSDK'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
end

target 'LifeStreamTests' do
pod 'SSKeychain'
pod 'LiveSDK'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
end
```

I then ran pod Install which created my workspace. When it was finished, I compiled the project but received the following compiler errors in the AlamoFire framework.

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'CFString!'
>
> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'CFString!'
>
> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'CFString!'

For the following code in `Manager.swift`

```
if let info = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary {
    let executable: AnyObject = info[kCFBundleExecutableKey] ?? "Unknown"
    let bundle: AnyObject = info[kCFBundleIdentifierKey] ?? "Unknown"
    let version: AnyObject = info[kCFBundleVersionKey] ?? "Unknown"
```

I also received several other compiler errors in the same file such as

> Value of optional type 'NSURLSessionConfiguration?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

```
self.session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: nil)
```

> Missing argument for parameter #2 in call

```
completionHandler(sessionDidReceiveChallenge!(session, challenge))
```

There are some other compiler errors in Request.swift as well. My question is, are these a result of changes made in Swift 2.0? If so, is there an ETA as to when Alamofire will have these issues fixed and published?

Comment: I would appreciate a comment from whomever downvoted me, explaining why so I can improve the question. I don't want to leave the question in a poor state if you feel it should be improved.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old, but you can do:

```
String(kCFBundleVersionKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error messages are telling you that you're using a type that cannot be used for subscripting.  `kCFBundleExecutableKey` and friends are `CFStringRef` literals.  You should convert them to `NSString` object using

```
kCFBundleExecutableKey as NSString
```

etc.

Or you could simply use the string values they are defined as:

```
"CFBundleExecutable"
"CFBundleIdentifier"
"CFBundleVersion"
```

Comment: That usage is in the `AlamoFire` framework, I was wondering if the pod is just broken. It's weird that they would ship a cocoa pod that doesn't compile. I'll tweak the framework to get it working; I'm curious if this worked fine in pre-swift2/Xcode 7 environments

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Swift is evolving quickly; are you using Swift 2.0 and they are using 1.2 perhaps?

Comment: I am using 2.0. Wasn't sure though because this seems like a framework thing and not necessarily a language change. It's possible it changed in iOS9. I don't know

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this was to use the new `Alamofire Swift-2` branch on github. I adjusted my podfile

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
```

and re-installed the pods. Once it was done, I was able to build the project without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should update Almofire to Swift-2

You can fix those lines with this:

```
let executable = String(info[kCFBundleExecutableKey as String]) ?? "Unknown"
            let bundle = String(info[kCFBundleIdentifierKey as String]) ?? "Unknown"
            let version = String(info[kCFBundleVersionKey as String]) ?? "Unknown"
            let os: AnyObject = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().operatingSystemVersionString ?? "Unknown"
```

but I recommend that you update the library Almofire